# Babel v7? Is it core-v7, cli-v7? or all packages are upgraded?

Tags: javascript, upgrade, babeljs

I understand Babel is a monorepo and contains a lot of packages like core, cli, plugins, presets etc.

1. When they say upgrade to Babel `v7.x.x`, what do they really mean. Does it mean, upgrade each of the `packages` in monorepo to `v7.x.x`?
2. If I upgrade my core package to `babel-core-v7.x.x`. Then does it mean if I still supply `stage-x` presets in `.babelrc`, core package won't understand it and hence won't transpile using the plugins in the preset.(Since `stage-presets` are deprecated in `v7.x.x`)
3. [Babel Docs for Decorator plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-decorators) Here they say, `In Babel 7, transform-decorators-legacy will be the default plugin in Stage-0.` What do they mean here, if stage presets i.e. `stage-x(0,1,2,3)` are deprecated.

Comment: Try asking this on there github repo.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit, this is what I found.

1. `Babel` is a monorepo that has a lot of packages in it. The main babel package that takes the raw code and transpile to a new code is babel-core. By itself, it does not do anything, it simply returns the same code.
2. `Babel-core` or `babel` can accept config which could contain a lot of plugins, presets(bundled set of plugins). These plugins are responsible for transipiling code. For Eg. You may use an ES6 arrow function in your code. Then you may run babel with a plugin that transpiles arrow functions to get the resulting ES5 version of arrow function.
3. Now Babel v7.x.x is a major(as per semantic versioning) version change(from 6.x.x to 7.x.x), hence it is expected to have breaking changes. Hence if you just change the babel core version, the code is expected to break. Hence they supply a migration guide as well.
4. With version 7.x.x, the way Plugins/Presets are mandated to return a function against version 6.x.x where it could return an object or function. Hence if you try to use a v6 plugin, that return an object with v7 of babel core, it will fail. Also they have removed stage-x presets. Hence if you have those in your config, it will break as well. There are a lot of such changes. Please refer to migration guide.
5. To answer #3, I confirmed with the team there, and the docs are not updated yet.